# Gorm: How do I set an integer column to null, and update the model in-memory?

Tags: go, go-gorm

As a simple background, I have a table `foo`, with a nullable int foreign key `bar_id`.  I have a function that removes the `bar` association from `foo`, aka set it to `NULL`.

I have tried everything: I tried using `sql.NullInt64` as the column type, and then

```
foo.BarId.Valid = false // even set Int64 = 0 for good measure
db.Save(&foo) // with LogMode(true)
```

`bar_id` was not updated in the UPDATE statement

I tried:

```
db.Raw("UPDATE foo SET bar_id = NULL WHERE id = ?", foo.ID).Row().Scan(&foo)
```

The SQL was correct thankfully, but the object is not updated.  I don't think my version of gorm has `Error` either.

I tried changing the type of Foo.BarId to an `*int64`, and setting the pointer to `nil`, but the output query didn't change `bar_id` to NULL.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it.  I need to specifically include the column in a `Select()`:

```
db.Model(&foo).Select("bar_id").Updates(map[string]interface{}{"bar_id": nil})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `gorm.Expr("NULL")` also like below :

```
db.Model(&foo).Select("bar_id").Updates(map[string]interface{}{"bar_id": gorm.Expr("NULL")})
```

you can use this also on `datetime` database field type.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```golang
//RemoveAllChildren  remove all the children
 func RemoveAllChildren(db *gorm.DB, dataEdit Mat) (Mat, error) {
     var matupdate Mat
     db.Where("id = ?", dataEdit.ID).First(&matupdate)
     if err := db.Model(&matupdate).Update("children_mat", gorm.Expr("NULL")); err != nil {
             return matupdate, errors.New("cannotUpdate")
     }
     return matupdate, nil
 }
```

refer to: https://gist.github.com/thanhtungka91/186dca4cd14d30581bb98193153a55bf